# Can grunt-shell interact with the user?

Tags: shell, gruntjs, bower, grunt-shell

Is there a way to allow user interact with internal command invoked by "grunt-shell" (or other task like "grunt-exec")?
I've such a config:

```
  grunt.initConfig({
     shell: {
        bower_install: {
           command: 'bower install'
       }
     }
  });
```

The problem is that sometimes scripts need to interact with user (e.g. bower prompts you to choose the package version) but when I run my "grunt shell" task, after the point where normally bower would ask user for choose, grunt task fails.

Workaround might be to work with bower dependencies so that it wont ask for choose but its not the soluton. Can I make grunt-shell commands works like normally invoked from shell?

Thanks for reply.

Comment: Your specific problem regarding bower might be for the same reason why `read` does not seem to echo the output when used within grunt-shell: the prompt gets only displayed when the command is issued from a terminal. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807982/prompt-for-input-in-using-the-grunt-shell-plugin. It's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

grunt-shell 1.1.2 can interact with the user via stdin. The following grunt-task  downloads a directory via ftp using wget and prompts me for a password:

```
shell: {
    target: {
        command: 'wget --ftp-user=some-user --ask-password ftp://some-ftp/directory/*'
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the parameters `-r -l0` to recursively download all subdirectories as well