# Prompt for input in using the grunt-shell plugin

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, gruntjs

I have a script I am trying to run with grunt using the grunt-shell plugin. This script prompts for input using `read -p "enter foo" bar`. When I run it, I get a cursor that correctly takes my input, but I don't see "enter foo".

I tried modifying the grunt-shell config to dump err, stderr, and stdout to the console, but they all come out empty once the command completes. The man page for read says about the -p flag "The prompt is displayed only if input is coming from a terminal.", which seems like it may be my issue since node is calling the prompt, but the read command is executing in my terminal, and I am entering input in a terminal, so why wouldn't that work?

So, my question is, is there any way to prompt for user input from the grunt-shell plugin?

Also, as a P.S., yes i know it would be very easy to just echo the prompt and deal with the input being below it, but dammit it's the principle of the thing.

Comment: "dammit it's the principle of the thing" +1 :D

Comment: After some tinkering, I think you're right... the fact that the command is actually being run through a Node `child_process` looks to be the culprit, and my guess is that the prompt from the `read` command is not actually `stdin` somehow, thus it isn't piped correctly to the console. Might be out of luck for the "principled" solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I redirected my code back to /dev/tty.
Ran it as `bash -c run.sh </dev/tty`

Comment: [Please use Answers exclusively to answer the question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/92107). To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have [sufficient reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). In the meantime, please do not use answers to post comments.